# JQuery animate background positions in multiple divs on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, scroll, jquery-animate

I have multiple divs on my page where I want to animate their background position onScroll, so here is what I have got for now

```
/* animate background possition on scroll */
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(y < $(".page-separator").offset().top && ( $(".page-separator").offset().top ) < ( y + $(window).height() ) ){
        $(this).css('background-position', '0% ' + parseInt(-y / 10) + 'px');
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work. I think it is because `$(this)`is not currently visible `$(".page-separator")` , can you please help me to fix it?

---

So I have modified my code here but I am stacked again, I can't pass parameter into .each jquery function

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".page-separator").each(function(y){
        //$(".page-separator").css('background-position', '0% ' + parseInt(-y / 10) + 'px');
        if( y < $(this).offset().top && ( $(this).offset().top ) < ( y + $(window).height() ) ){
            $(this).css('background-position', '0% ' + parseInt(-y / 10) + 'px');

        }console.log(y);
    });
});
```

when I see console.log(y) it only shows 0 1 2 nothing more, not the top position

Comment: Uhm, what is'nt working exactly? And `this` in that scope would of course be the `window`!

Comment: @adeneo I want to animate the background position of visible $(".page-separator") , I want to animate only for $(".page-separator") that user sees right now in his browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the `background-position` of the visible `.page-separator` elements, you'd do :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();

    $(".page-separator").filter(function() {
        return $(this).offset().top < (y + $(window).height()) &&
               $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > y;
    }).css('background-position', '0px ' + parseInt(-y / 10) + 'px');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RYZ3h/)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I didn't mean "visibility:visible", all .page-separator divs are "visibility:visible", but I want to animate the div that user sees right now in his browser

Comment: Nope your solution doesn't work, it animates ALL divs under .page-separator class not the current one that is seen in browser right now. I have modified my post, please see it

Comment: @Irakli - I've added a fiddle to the answer, to show it working when scrolling. Are you sure your background animation is working as intended ?

Answer (score 0):

`$(this) == $(window)` in this case. You should add one class (ex: 'animate') for all divs, and use it as selector (ex: `$('.animate')`)

Comment: It will not work because it will animate ALL the divs not the one that user sees right now in his browser

Comment: Down voted someone who tried to help you @Iraki?  Scandalous.

Comment: I just show you $(this) mean $(window). The selector just an advice, Please read carefully! you don't know how to check the div visible or not =))